# While calling function with pool, It shows the variable is not defined which is there in main (global)

Tags: python, python-3.x, salesforce, python-multiprocessing, simple-salesforce

May be my question looks simple *(or the Bug might be minor)* but I could not be able find the bug, really I struggled a lot to figure out the issue.

I've created a Framework to Extract the Data from Salesforce with Simple Salesforce package, but I've encountered with the bug when I'm using multiprocessing.

My code is pretty much straight forward but tedious. I don't want to paste entire code here, So here is [my Code from my GitHub](https://github.com/ParvathiRajan/salesforce-extraction/blob/master/sf_extraction.py).

**Issue:**

When I'm calling this [Extract Data function](https://github.com/ParvathiRajan/salesforce-extraction/blob/master/sf_extraction.py#L226) with Pool, the variable which is there in the `__name__ == '__main__'` is not working.

> In Other words I'm getting, **NameError: name 'SFAPI' is not defined** - But It's there in the main as Global Variable and It's working without pool (A single call).

**Execution Example:**

```
python "E:\Documents\myPy\SF Project\sf_extraction.py" -pr data_extraction -tn Opportunity Account
```

**Small Snippet from my code, where I'm getting issues:**

```
def ExtractData(table_name):
    logging.info('Extract Data for Table Name: ' + table_name + ' at ' + getCurrDatetime())
    try:
        rec_count = getRecordCount(table_name)
        print(rec_count)
        if int(rec_count) == 0:
            logging.info('There is no data to Extract for {}'.format(table_name))
        else:
            soql = SFAPI.CreateSOQL(table_name)
            data = SFAPI.ExecuteSOQL(soql, is_count=0)
            extract_file_nm = table_name + '_' + db_name + '_'  + sc_name + '_' + curr_datetime + '.csv'
            print(data)
            print(type(data))
            extract_file = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(script_path,extract_file_nm))
            data.to_csv(extract_file, index=False)
            logging.info('Data has been extrcated as {} at {}'.format(extract_file, getCurrDatetime()))

    except Exception as e:
        logging.info('Error in Extraction')
        err_msg = "FATAL_ERROR: In the ExtractData Function : {0}\n\n{1}".format(e, traceback.format_exc())
        raise Exception(str(err_msg))
```

**Place or Snippet from where I'm calling this:**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        SFAPI = SalesforceAPICall(username=config['username'],
                            password=config['password'],
                            security_token=config['sf_token'],
                            )

        if len(table_name) != 0 and 'data_extraction' in process_nm:
            try: 
                if len(table_name) == 1:
                    print(table_name[0])
                    ExtractData(table_name[0])
                if type(table_name) == list and len(table_name) > 1:
                    #p = Pool(processes=int(processes))
                    print('Calling Pool : ' + str(os.cpu_count()))
                    #out = p.map(ExtractData, table_name)
                    #p.close()
                    #p.join()
                    p = Pool()
                    print(table_name)
                    x = p.map(ExtractData, table_name)
                    x.get()
                    p.close()
                    p.join()
            except Exception as e:
                if len(table_name) > 1:
                    p.terminate()
                    p.join()
                logging.error("Process Failed - " + str(e))
    except Exception as e:
        chk_err('FATAL_ERROR: ' + " from main exception : {0}\n\n{1}".format(e, traceback.format_exc()))
```

You can very well [refer my code in GitHub](https://github.com/ParvathiRajan/salesforce-extraction/blob/master/sf_extraction.py) if it looks clumsy or if you feel this is not enough amount of information to fix.

> Again **it might be a small Bug,** Hope You Understand what I'm trying to convey !!! Thanks in
>   Advance !!!

Regards,
Parvathirajan Natarajan